# spring-cloud context bootstrap ignores disabled spring shutdown hook in main context

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

We are implementing our own shutdown hook and want to disable the default that comes with spring. It worked fine in spring application that doesn't make use of spring-cloud.

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplicationBuilder(NoaApp.class).build();
app.setRegisterShutdownHook(false);
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = app.run(args);
GracefulShutdownHook.register(applicationContext);
```

SpringApplication fires an event which causes BootstrapApplicationListener to initialize a new context with the registerShutdownHook flag set to the default true, which registers the shutdown hook.

Is there a clean way to get around this?

Comment: No, not at this time. How would you get the bootstrap context to register with your hook? Or would simply calling setRegisterShutdownHook(false) be ok?

Comment: I only need to disable the spring hook in the contexts spring-cloud is creating.  I am registering my own java shutdown hook in the main class.

Comment: Looks like it was fixed in a later version of spring-cloud  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/commit/96ec2d32ea0467abab26b33776667cb7c37533d3

Comment: Giving the version would have been helpful. You're likely using an unsupported version.

Comment: yeah, you're right, version would have been helpful. We're on 1.0.3 , fix in version 1.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were on spring-cloud 1.0.3, fixed in version 1.1.0